# Julia Lang: Negative Binary Number Representation

Tags: binary, numbers, julia

How do I represent a negative number in its binary representation in Julia?

Here is what I've tried:

```
Int(0b10)
```

returns 2, as expected. Now, the first bit should represent to sign of the number and thus one might expect the following to compile:

```
Int(1b10)
```

but it does not. In fact it returns the following error:

```
UndefVarError: b01 not defined
```

And of course:

```
bin(-1)
```

returns

"-1"

which is not really the binary representation of the negative number.

Any ideas?

*EDIT* - Found the solution:

```
 unsigned(-1)
 0xffffffffffffffff
```

and then all you have to do is:

```
bin(unsigned(-1))
"1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You have written a nice question. I encourage you to [to answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) as a real answer, instead of editing the question -- such a thing is well-received, and you can also accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like many other languages, Julia uses `Two's complement` for representing signed integers. To represent a negative number, you can use `bits` to get its bit representation a.k.a taking the two's complement of the binary representation of its positive part:

```
help?> bits
search: bits isbits flipbits! bitbroadcast bitrand BitArray BitVector BitMatrix signbit LibGit2

  bits(n)

  A string giving the literal bit representation of a number.

     Example
    ≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡

  julia> bits(4)
  "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100"

  julia> bits(2.2)
  "0100000000000001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011010"

julia> bits(-1)
"1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111"
```

Comment: Thx for the answer. But I think what I tried to accomplish is not actually possible since: "Unsigned integers are input and output using the 0x prefix", hence it's not actually possible to use the connotation for negative values.

Comment: @user2550228 I don't know why you attempted to convert it to unsigned integers. To get the binary representation of a negative number, all we need is to take the two's complement of its positive binary representation.

Comment: I tried to express a negative value using the "0x.." notation. It was for an exercise where it came in handy.

Comment: @user2550228 Though a little bit insane, but you can express several bits using the `0x` notation then convert it to a signed integer. For example, `reinterpret(Int8, 0xff)` returns `-1`.

Comment: @张实唯: Wow, that actually works. Indeed this is the desired effect. Very nice!